# JQuery .resize function running code x times resized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I now use CSS Media queries for my carousels and the buttons. But for the scroll animation to work properly I need Jquery. The problem I'm having is that if I resize to a device resolution and back to desktop, doing that 3 times means the code will run 3 times. so doing that 6 times, it will run the code 6 times.

Jquery:

```
function setupButtons() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1198) {
        if ($('#carousel-a').is(':visible')) { // desktop
            $("#OnzeDiensten").click(function(a) {
                a.preventDefault();

                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#OnzeDienstenHeading").offset().top - 80
                }, 2000);
                alert(" MAIN!");
            });

        }
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 992) { // device
        if ($('#carousel-d').is(':visible')) {
            $("#OnzeDienstenDevices").click(function(b) {
                b.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#OnzeDienstenHeadingDevice").offset().top - 80
                }, 2000);
                alert("DEVICE!");
            });
        }
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 1198 && $(window).width() > 992) { // tablet
        if ($('#carousel-e').is(':visible')) {
            $("#OnzeDienstenResponsive").click(function(c) {
                c.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#OnzeDienstenHeadingResponsive").offset().top - 80
                }, 2000);
                alert("RESPONSIVE!");
            });
        }
    }
}

function resizeAnimatedScreenButton() {
    var resizeTimeout;
    $(window).resize(function() {
            clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
            if ($(window).width() > 1198) {
                resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    if ($('#carousel-a').is(':visible')) { // desktop
                        $("#OnzeDiensten").click(function(a) {
                            a.preventDefault();
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $("#OnzeDienstenHeading").offset().top - 80
                            }, 2000);
                            alert(" MAIN!");
                            $('#carousel-a').unbind();
                        });
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
            if ($(window).width() < 992) { // device
                resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    if ($('#carousel-d').is(':visible')) {
                        $("#OnzeDienstenDevices").click(function(b) {
                            b.preventDefault();
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $("#OnzeDienstenHeadingDevice").offset().top - 80
                            }, 2000);
                            alert("DEVICE!");
                            $('#carousel-d').unbind();
                        });
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
            if ($(window).width() < 1198 && $(window).width() > 992) { // tablet
                resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    if ($('#carousel-e').is(':visible')) {
                        $("#OnzeDienstenResponsive").click(function(c) {
                            c.preventDefault();
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $("#OnzeDienstenHeadingResponsive").offset().top - 80
                            }, 2000);
                            alert("RESPONSIVE!");
                            $('#carousel-e').unbind();
                        });
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
        });
} // end resizeanimation

$(document).ready(function() {
    setupButtons();
    resizeAnimatedScreenButton();
});
```

CSS Media Queries:

```
 @media (min-width:1198px)
   .carousele, .carouseld, .DienstResponsive, .DienstDevice {
   display:none!important;
}
 @media (max-width:1197px) and (min-width: 993px)
 .carousela, .carouseld, .DienstDesktop, .DienstDevice {
    display:none;
 }
 @media (max-width:992px)
 .carousele, .carousela, .DienstDesktop, .DienstDevice {
    display:none;
 }
```

Comment: CSS media queries.

Comment: Yeah, I use those too, but instead using CSS media queries, I wanted to try JQuery to improve my Jquery 'skills'. I already got the code to just fix this with CSS, but I really want to know what I'm doing wrong with my JQuery code.

Comment: What you're doing wrong = using jQuery to emulate CSS media queries :) It's WAY heavier and you don't even cache your jQuery objects (`var $carouselA = $('#carousel-a')` and reuse that) so you just kill performance

Comment: Hmm, didn't really think about performance. Might as well throw the jquery code away and use the CSS Media queries.

Thanks anyway for the heads up!

Comment: @JeremyThille The buttons and carousels will show now through Media Queries, however, I still have the problem with the jquery scroll animation, It's still the same problem. Resizing to device and back, doing that 3 times means the code will run 3 times.. Still have no solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you attach a `.click` listener inside the `scroll` callback :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   $("#OnzeDiensten").click(function(a) { ... }
})
```

This means that you are attaching one click listener every time the window is resized by 1 pixel. So if you resize the window by 100 pixels, you attach 100 listeners (!) And when the button is clicked, the code runs 100 times.

Even worse, as I already said in the comments, you are not caching your jQuery objects. So jQuery must traverse the whole DOM and look for each of `$('#carousel-a')`, `$('html, body')`, `$("#OnzeDienstenDevices")`, `$("#OnzeDienstenHeadingDevice")` and `$('#carousel-d')` a HUNDRED times, and build this many jQuery objects a HUNDRED times, every time! This is just horrendous, performance-wise.

So 1. CACHE your objects

```
var $OnzeDiensten = $("#OnzeDiensten");
// and then RE-USE them at will
$OnzeDiensten.click(...)
$OnzeDiensten.animate(...)
$OnzeDiensten.css(...)
```

and 2. cancel previous click listeners before re-attaching them :

```
$OnzeDiensten
    .off("click") // Remove any previous click listeners
    .on("click", function(){ // attaches ONE click listener
       // do stuff once
    })
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I actually didn't know caching in JQuery could save on performance.